# Infinite Scroll Masonry page loses formatting after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, infinite-scroll, masonry

I have an MVC project in which an Infinite Scroll page is used in conjunction with masonry blocks.

The initial load work just fine but when I load the new data, it appears to have no formatting at all.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

[image: Masonry Working]

[image: Masonry Not Working]

Here' the code

The VIEW

```
@model List<Business.Vent>

<div id="VentListDiv">
<div class="blog_masonry_3col">
    <div class="container content grid-boxes">
            @{Html.RenderAction("VentList", "Test", new { Model = Model });}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">

    var BlockNumber = 2;  //Infinate Scroll starts from second block
    var NoMoreData = false;
    var inProgress = false;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && !NoMoreData && !inProgress) {

            inProgress = true;
            $("#loadingDiv").show();

            $.post("@Url.Action("InfinateScroll", "Test")", { "BlockNumber": BlockNumber },
                    function (data) {

                        BlockNumber = BlockNumber + 1;
                        NoMoreData = data.NoMoreData;
                        $("#VentListDiv").append(data.HTMLString);
                        $("#loadingDiv").hide();
                        inProgress = false;
                    });
        }
    });
</script>
}
```

PARTIAL VIEW

```
@model List<Business.Vent>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div class="grid-boxes-in">
    <div class="grid-boxes-caption">
        <ul class="list-inline grid-boxes-news">
            <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> July 06, 2014</li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> 06</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>@item.MyText</p>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int BlockSize = 5;
        var Vent = Business.Vent.GetListCount(1, BlockSize);
        return View(Vent);
    }

    public ActionResult VentList(List<Business.Vent> Model)
    {
        return PartialView(Model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult InfinateScroll(int BlockNumber)
    {
        //////////////// THis line of code only for demo. Needs to be removed ///////////////
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        int BlockSize = 5;
        var Vent = Business.Vent.GetListCount(BlockNumber, BlockSize);

        Business.Vent.JsonModel jsonModel = new Business.Vent.JsonModel();
        jsonModel.NoMoreData = Vent.Count < BlockSize;
        jsonModel.HTMLString = RenderPartialViewToString("VentList", Vent);

        return Json(jsonModel);
    }

    protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTML was returned in a JSON string, when you are appending it to the VentListDiv, it is being treated as a string and not as HTML, try converting to HTML first:

```
$("#VentListDiv").append($.parseHTML(data.HTMLString));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that but got the same result.